# How to display the database name in json

Tags: php, mysql, json

Am fetching values from `mysql` to `json`. All my data's are showing properly now i want to display **database name** inside json. any help can be appreciated.

**json.php code :**

```
       <?php   
       $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "recruiter");  
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM recruiter";  
       $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
       $json_array = array();  
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
       {  
            $json_array[] = $row;

       }  
       echo (json_encode($json_array));     
       ?>
```

Output:

```
{
    "here i want db name":[
        {
            "job_id":"1",
            "job_title":"Java developer",
            "job_description":"Java description",
            "job_details":"details",
            "job_skills":"java",
            "job_min_exp":"0 Yr",
            "job_max_exp":"2 Yrs",
            "company_name":"",
            "job_location":"",
            "industry":"",
            "department":"",
            "job_role":"",
            "owner_name":"",
            "owner_mobile":"",
            "owner_email":"",
            "owner_description":" "
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share a sample result you're trying to get. Where would you like the database name to appear?

Comment: This is unclear - you already know the database name.  What is the issue here?

Comment: Such an odd need indeed. One way: `echo json_encode(array('Database_name'=>$json_array));`

Comment: What would `json_encode ([$database=> $json_array])` would return ?

Comment: it shows `undefined varaible` on echo line @Zyigh

Answer (score 3):

As per your output, Understand is database name is array under the multidimensional array. To show database name inside the JSON.

**Try this code**

```
<?php   
   $database_name = "recruiter";
   $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", $database_name);  
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM recruiter";  
   $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
   $json_array = array();  
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
   {  
        $json_array[] = $row;

   }  

   echo json_encode(array($database_name => array($json_array)));
?>
```